# nvidia-331 drivers gives black screen at startup

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have a laptop Asus K53s with nVidia GeForce GT 540M. I (freshly) installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and set up `nvidia-331` proprietary driver for the graphic card. I set prime option to run nVidia acceleration and it used to work fine.

On 25th Janaury 2015, there was an Ubuntu software update (from apt log I saw it was updated `nvidia-settings`, and other stuff) after which I see a black screen instead of the login screen.

I tried to switch to intel graphic card (sudo prime-switch intel) but it gives erros, it is not able to switch to intel.

I tried to purge `nvidia*` and then install `nvidia-340`, but it still shows black screen instead of login.

The only way to use my laptop is to install:

```
apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

which is the driver `nvidia-304`. But it uses the intel graphics card. It is not possible switch to nVidia neither with

```
sudo prime-switch nvidia
```

nor with

```
nvidia-setting graphic utility.
```

I need to use my nVidia card for graphic acceleration (OpenGL). At the moment the laptop is too slow for my activity (CAD).

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the driver ? Try downloading the driver from NVidia Official Website and installing it.

Comment: No, I did not try NVidia official driver downloaded from NVidia web site because I am worried to mess my Ubuntu system up. Initially I just tried the NVidia proprietary drivers available in Ubuntu "Additional Drivers" window. I always got black login screen with all of them. 
Then I tried to add NVidia repository: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mamarley/nvidia and then install nvidia-340. Unfortunately I get again black login screen. If you think official NVidia can fix the problem and not mess my Ubuntu up I will try.

Comment: What versions is your xorg stack?

Comment: I used a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04.1 64bit which I do not have with me now. That version of Ubuntu should use X Server 1.15.1

Answer (score 3):

I eventually solved my problem with my nvidia.

I found the fix on the post #15 of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1362848

Here how I fixed in details:

Log out and go to the console:

CTRL-ALT-F1

if (like me) you tried to install latest nvidia driver (nvidia-340 ...), you need to revert back with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then copy all xorg config files in a temporary dir:

```
cd
mkdir temp
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf* ./temp/
```

Then clean, update, upgrade and reboot the system:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Go to the console:

CTRL-ALT-F1

Install nvidia 331:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
```

Copy the old xorg.conf made by nvidia  back in its directory:

```
sudo cp temp/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And edit it (I used vi, you may prefer nano):

```
sudo vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

To be as the following:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Eventually reboot the system:

```
sudo reboot
```

Now I have nvidia set as graphic card and the hardware acceleration works fine.

Answer (score 0):

With installation of nvidia drivers, you need to be very careful and calm. Different versions of nvidia work differently with some groups of laptops. This update may screw something up, but do not worry - try to

```
$ sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime nvidia-331 nvidia-331-updates
```

**If something goes wrong**

...and you will reboot the system then black screen appears again:

1. switch to another tty by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.
2. uninstall all stuff connected with nvidia by running `sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'`.
3. reboot system `sudo reboot` and try with other versions of nvidia (310, 313, 319 or re-install again 331, but with or without "updates" package).

> The combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> you will return to graphical mode again in you are in other tty.